# periodically flushing new documents to an index using lucene

Tags: java

I need to flush the index periodically.that's mean that the
index will be regularly updated as the document being added.what do
you reckon is the solution for this? I need a sample source code to be
able to flush an index.

ok just like this source code below.

```
public class SimpleFileIndexer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           File indexDir = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/adi");
           File dataDir = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/adi");
           String suffix = "txt";

           SimpleFileIndexer indexer = new SimpleFileIndexer();

           int numIndex = indexer.index(indexDir, dataDir, suffix);

           System.out.println("Total files indexed " + numIndex);
    }

    private int index(File indexDir, File dataDir, String suffix) throws Exception {
           IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
                           FSDirectory.open(indexDir),
                           new SimpleAnalyzer(),
                           true,
                           IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
           indexWriter.setUseCompoundFile(false);

           indexDirectory(indexWriter, dataDir, suffix);

           int numIndexed = indexWriter.maxDoc();
           indexWriter.optimize();
           indexWriter.close();

           return numIndexed;
    }

    private void indexDirectory(IndexWriter indexWriter, File dataDir, String suffix) throws IOException {
           File[] files = dataDir.listFiles();
           for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                   File f = files[i];
                   if (f.isDirectory()) {
                           indexDirectory(indexWriter, f, suffix);
                   }
                   else {
                           indexFileWithIndexWriter(indexWriter, f, suffix);
                   }
           }
    }

    private void indexFileWithIndexWriter(IndexWriter indexWriter, File f, String suffix) throws IOException {
           if (f.isHidden() || f.isDirectory() || !f.canRead() || !f.exists()) {
                   return;
           }
           if (suffix!=null && !f.getName().endsWith(suffix)) {
                   return;
           }
           System.out.println("Indexing file " + f.getCanonicalPath());

           Document doc = new Document();
           doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f)));
           doc.add(new Field("filename", f.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

           indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
    }
}
```

the above source code can index documents when given the directory of
text files. now what I am asking is how can I made the code to run
continuously? what class should I use? so that everytime there is new
documents added to that directory then lucene will index those
documents automatically, can you help me out on this one. I really
need to know what is the best solution.

Comment: I don't see where 'flushing' comes into it.

Comment: Just remove all the code you've posted here, and replace it with "Can I watch a directory and periodically index it with Lucene, without re-indexing everything?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene can't do this by itself. You will need to monitor the filesystem for that.

Look at [How to detect filesystem has changed in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450926/how-to-detect-filesystem-has-changed-in-java).

Comment: can you tell me of how to use Jnotify? I find it would be a great idea to have a class that will monitor any directories that I want, either adding,deleting and removing documents in a directory. I mean how can I include Jnotify in the code I included above. thanks

Comment: If you're not a programmer, you probably shouldn't be on SO. Anyway, here are the snippets: http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/sample.html